# count sum of list using tail recursive function in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am doing assignment for my college. I need to create recursive function.

My `list_t` interface contain following functions:

```
List Interface
The file recursive.h defines the type "list_t" and the following operations on lists:
// EFFECTS: returns true if list is empty, false otherwise
bool list_isEmpty​ (const list_t& list);
// EFFECTS: returns an empty list.
list_t list_make​ ();
// EFFECTS: given the list (list) make a new list consisting of
// the new element followed by the elements of the
// original list.
list_t list_make​ (int elt, const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the first element of list
int list_first​ (const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the list containing all but the first element of list
list_t list_rest​ (const list_t& list);
// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints list to cout.
void list_print​ (const list_t& list);
```

Please note sum function need to be tail recursive and I can't use static or global variable.

until now I have come with this which is gives me wrong answer:

```
int sum(list_t list) {
    if(list.get_rest_list().is_empty())
    return list.get_first_elt() + sum(list.get_rest_list());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite that function with proper indentation:

```
int sum(list_t list)
{
    if(list.get_rest_list().is_empty())
        return list.get_first_elt() + sum(list.get_rest_list());

    // what to return here?
}
```

In addition to the flawed logic, you don't have all control paths covered with `return` statement, which causes indeterminate value to be returned if the condition is not satisfied.

(Not so) Corrected code:

```
int sum(list_t list)
{
    if(list.get_rest_list().is_empty())
        return list.get_first_elt();

    return list.get_first_elt() + sum(list.get_rest_list());
}
```

You can rewrite this using ternary operator, if you like.

But what if you pass an empty `list_t`? Better do this:

```
int sum(list_t list)
{
    if(list.is_empty())
        return 0;

    return list.get_first_elt() + sum(list.get_rest_list());
}
```

Comment: can you also tell me why this function always return true .`bool list_contains(list_t list, int elt){

  if(list.is_empty())
        return false;
 
  if(list.get_first_elt()==elt){
   return true;
  }else{
   list_contains(list.get_rest_list(),elt);
  } 
 }`